# scikit-learn ValueError: dimension mismatch

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

This is my first time posting here. For the past couple of days I have been trying to teach myself scikit-learn. But recently I have encountered an error that has been nagging me for quite some time.

My goal is simply to train a NB classifier `cli` so that I can feed it an arbitrary list of strings called `new_doc` and it will predict what class the string is likely to belong to.

This is what my program looks like:

```
#Importing stuff
import numpy as np
import pylab
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, HashingVectorizer, CountVectorizer
from sklearn import metrics

#Opening the csv file
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')

#Randomising the rows in the file
df = df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index))

#Extracting features from text, define target y and data X
vect = CountVectorizer()
X = vect.fit_transform(df['Features'])
y = df['Target']

#Partitioning the data into test and training set
SPLIT_PERC = 0.75
split_size = int(len(y)*SPLIT_PERC)
X_train = X[:split_size]
X_test = X[split_size:]
y_train = y[:split_size]
y_test = y[split_size:]

#Training the model
clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Evaluating the results
print "Accuracy on training set:"
print clf.score(X_train, y_train)
print "Accuracy on testing set:"
print clf.score(X_test, y_test)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print "Classification Report:"
print metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred)

#Predicting new data
new_doc = ["MacDonalds", "Walmart", "Target", "Starbucks"]
trans_doc = vect.transform(new_doc) #extracting features
y_pred = clf.predict(trans_doc) #predicting
```

But when I run the program I get the following error on the last row:

```
y_pred = clf.predict(trans_doc)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 62, in predict
    jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 441, in _joint_log_likelihood
    return (safe_sparse_dot(X, self.feature_log_prob_.T)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 175, in safe_sparse_dot
    ret = a * b
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 334, in __mul__
    raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

So apparently it has something to do with the dimension of the term-document matrixes.

When I check the dimensions of trans_doc, X_train and X_test i get:

```
>>> trans_doc.shape
(4, 4)
>>> X_train.shape
(145314, 28750)
>>> X_test.shape
(48439, 28750)
```

In order for `y_pred = clf.predict(trans_doc)` to work I need to (from what I understand it) transform `new_doc` into a term-document matrix with the dimensions `(4, 28750)`. But I don't know of any methods within `CountVectorizer` that lets me do this.

Comment: Are you certain that the issue is with exactly the code that you posted?
Your code should work, if you called ``vect.fit_transform(new_doc)`` you would get the error that you showed.
Btw, you should call ``fit_transform`` only on the training part of the data, not the test part.

Comment: THANKS! It actually works now. I have been banging my head against the problem for several days, meticulously exhausting every possibility. I guess I must have written something differently when I wrote the code down here. But I don't know what or how since I just copy pasted the code. I know for sure that I used transform() and not fit_transform because I looked it up in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484310/scipy-and-scikit-learn-valueerror-dimension-mismatch?rq=1.