# CountVectorizer MultinomialNB ValueError: dimension mismatch

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes, multinomial, countvectorizer

I am trying to make my MultinomialNB work. I use CountVectorizer on my training and test set and of course there are different words in both setzs. So I see, why the error

```
ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

occurs, but I dont know how to fix it. I tried `CountVectorizer().transform` instead of `CountVectorizer().fit_transform` as was suggested in an other post ([SciPy and scikit-learn - ValueError: Dimension mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484310/scipy-and-scikit-learn-valueerror-dimension-mismatch)) but that just gives me

```
NotFittedError: CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.
```

how can I use CountVectorizer  right?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import sklearn.feature_extraction

df = data
y = df["meal_parent_category"]
X = df['name_cleaned']
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3)
X_train = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(X_test)
algo = MultinomialNB()
algo.fit(X_train,y_train)
y = algo.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after asking this question I figured it out :)
Here is the solution with vocabulary and such:

```
df = train
y = df["meal_parent_category_cleaned"]
X = df['name_cleaned']
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3)
vectorizer_train = CountVectorizer()
X_train = vectorizer_train.fit_transform(X_train)
vectorizer_test = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vectorizer_train.vocabulary_)
X_test = vectorizer_test.transform(X_test)
algo = MultinomialNB()
algo.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = algo.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
```

Comment: You could have used `X_test=vectorizer_train.transform(X_test)`, instead of defining a new one.

Comment: Oh, I lake that. Thank you :)