# Explanation of "Dimension mismatch" after using fit_transform on testing data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I was reading some code about NLP and saw that `X_test` does not have `fit_transform` when assigned (last line of code below).

When I tried to do it with `fit_transform` like the `X_train`and continued to use a predictive model it returned:

> ValueError: dimension mismatch

This question is about that case: [SciPy and scikit-learn - ValueError: Dimension mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484310/scipy-and-scikit-learn-valueerror-dimension-mismatch)

What I would like is a simple explanation as to why it occurs be cause I don't understand it clearly.

Below is the code I have:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

categories = ['alt.atheism', 'comp.graphics']
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories,  
                                      remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))
newsgroups_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test', categories=categories,  
                                     remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))
y_train = newsgroups_train.target
y_test = newsgroups_test.target
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(newsgroups_train.data)
X_test = vectorizer.transform(newsgroups_test.data) #here is the cause of the error if it had 'fit_transform' instead
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform()`, it first counts the number of unique vocabulary (feature) in your data and then its frequencies. Your training and test data do not have the same number of unique vocabulary. Thus, the dimension of your `X_test` and `X_train` does not match if you `.fit_transform()` on each of your train and test data. Therefore, your predictive model gets lost and gives you dimension mismatch error.

If you `.fit_transform()` on `X_train` and then just `.transform()` on `X_test`, you only count the vocabulary included in `X_train`. This ignores any vocabulary included only in `X_test`, thus matches the number of features.

**EDIT:** I have written a small example.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

city = ['London Moscow Washington',
        'Washington Boston']

president = ['Adams Washington',
             'Jefferson']

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
```

First, `.fit_transform(city)`.

```
X_city = vectorizer.fit_transform(city)
X_city.toarray()

>>>array([[0.        , 0.6316672 , 0.6316672 , 0.44943642],
          [0.81480247, 0.        , 0.        , 0.57973867]])
```

Then, `.transform(president)` based on the fit above.

```
vectorizer.transform(president).toarray()

>>>array([[0., 0., 0., 1.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Finally, `.fit_transform(president)`.

```
X_president = vectorizer.fit_transform(president)
X_president.toarray()

>>>array([[0.70710678, 0.        , 0.70710678],
          [0.        , 1.        , 0.        ]])
```

It comes down to matching the dimension between train and test data for your model.

Comment: Sounds like it makes sense, do you have material to back up this claim or make an example please?

Comment: The examples given in the documentation page and source code explain this well. (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html and https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py)

Comment: Actually they don't explain it, they just follow that trend of doing it that way.Please write some explanatory code of how is it to do .fit_transform()  and transform on each part.

Comment: Ok, I see that with the first approach it keeps the same number of values as you said, what I don't get is why it was 8 values that appeared in the first example and why 6 values in the latter. I mean why those numbers exactly? and also what these values represent.

Comment: There are two lists of words for each `city` and `president`, so 2 rows for both transformed arrays. There are four unique cities and three unique presidents, so if you `vectorizer.fit(city)` and then `vectorizer.transform(president)` you look for the name of cities from the list of president. There is only one (Washington). If you `.fit_transform(president)` you count presidents from the list of `president`. What those numbers mean? wikipedia page explains quite well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf You should have some idea of what `TfidfVectorizer()` does before using it.

Comment: In your last block of code, why there are 6 numbers? and since they are all unique in the 'president' list why there are varying values?at that point the 'city' list is not related.

Comment: `Adams Washington` is the document entry #1 and `Jefferson` is the document entry #2 for `president`. There are 3 unique president name, thus 3 columns. Yes, `city` is not related. Those numbers are different since `TfidfVectorizer()` normalizes each row with a L2 norm by default.