# Predict topics for new documents in CorEx gives dimension mismatch error in predict function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, transform

I used the following script for predicting the topics for new documents, but I got an error.

**Edit:** The training phase is as bellow:

```
train_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english', max_features=5610, binary=True)
doc_word = vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)

# Transform data into a sparse matrix
doc_word = ss.csr_matrix(doc_word)
words = list(np.asarray(vectorizer.get_feature_names()))

# final step of preprocessing where we remove all integers from our set of words.
not_digit_inds = [ind for ind, word in enumerate(words) if not word.isdigit()]
doc_word = doc_word[:, not_digit_inds]
words = [word for ind, word in enumerate(words) if not word.isdigit()]

# Train the CorEx topic model
topic_model = ct.Corex(n_hidden=5, max_iter=200, verbose=True, seed=2)

topic_model.fit(doc_word, words=words, anchors=anchor_words, anchor_strength=2)
```

The prediction script is as bellow:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english', max_features=5610, binary=True)
doc_word = vectorizer.transform(list(docs['Processed Comment']))
doc_word = ss.csr_matrix(doc_word)

corex_model.predict(doc_word)
```

and I get this error when calling `predict()`

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\corextopic\corextopic.py", line 247, in predict
    def predict(self, X):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\corextopic\corextopic.py", line 214, in transform
    def transform(self, X, details=False):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\corextopic\corextopic.py", line 417, in calculate_latent
    def calculate_latent(self, X, theta):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 346, in dot
    def dot(self, other):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 453, in __mul__
    def __mul__(self, other):
ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484310/valueerror-dimension-mismatch) solution:

```
vector = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=train_vectorizer.vocabulary_) 
doc_word = vector.transform(list(docs['Processed Comment']))
doc_word = ss.csr_matrix(doc_word)

corex_model.predict(doc_word)
```

and got a similar error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3457, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-384c0808407f>", line 4, in <module>
    corex_model.predict(doc_word)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\corextopic\corextopic.py", line 248, in predict
    return self.transform(X, details=False)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\corextopic\corextopic.py", line 221, in transform
    p_y_given_x, _, log_z = self.calculate_latent(X, self.theta)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\corextopic\corextopic.py", line 425, in calculate_latent
    log_pygx_unnorm[1] = self.log_p_y + c1 + X.dot(info1)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 359, in dot
    return self * other
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 516, in __mul__
    raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

`doc_word` dimension in the training phase is 5549 while in the test phase is 5610 (the same as max_features). So in `corextopic.py` this command fail: `X.dot(info1)`

Comment: Have you **fit** the CountVectorizer before attempting to transform with it?

Comment: @desertnaut yes, in training phase, I used `vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)` to fit the `CountVectorizer`.

Comment: But you seem to define it again in your code, and running `.transform` without having run `.fit` or `.fit_transform` before; please clarity - post a [mre].

Comment: @desertnaut in the second solution, I used `train_vectorizer` that is fitted by `fit_transform()` during the training.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The commands after `fit_transform()` in traning phase, change the training data. So same steps needed to be done after `transform()` in test phase:

```
vector = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=train_vectorizer.vocabulary_) 
doc_word = vector.transform(list(docs['Processed Comment']))
doc_word = ss.csr_matrix(doc_word)

not_digit_inds = [ind for ind, word in enumerate(words) if not word.isdigit()]
doc_word = doc_word[:, not_digit_inds]

corex_model.predict(doc_word)
```